# Publishing app to Opera Mobile store

Tags: mobile, app-store, opera

I have uploaded an app to opera mobile store about a week but i can't enable my Application! How long the verifity process takes? Or why i can't enable it?

Comment: Have you contacted Opera Mobile support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verification takes only about 12 hours. You should have received an email from them. If you have not then you either have not finished your application completely or you have a typo in your email address.